# Why can't I query by reference with Spring Data Jdbc?

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I created a query method using a Reference from another Aggregate.

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, onConstructor_=@PersistenceConstructor)
public static class Book {

    public static Book of(Author author) {
        return new Book(null, AggregateReference.to(author.id));
    }

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private AggregateReference<Author, Long>  authorId;
}
```

```java
interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

    List<Book> findBooksByAuthorId(Long  authorId);
}
```

But I got the following exception:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot query by reference: authorId
    at
```

I have checked the source below.
But I don't understand why it throws an exception.

```
org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.JdbcQueryCreator.validateProperty(JdbcQueryCreator.java:146)
```

```java
        private static void validateProperty(PersistentPropertyPathExtension path) {
         .....

        if (path.getRequiredPersistentPropertyPath().getLeafProperty().isReference()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("Cannot query by reference: %s", path.getRequiredPersistentPropertyPath().toDotPath()));
        }
    }
```

Why can't I create a query method on a Reference?

The source for your reference is here.
https://github.com/yangwansu/try-spring-data-jdbc/blob/main/src/test/java/masil/example/springdata/jdbc/ch9_7/QueryToAggregateReferenceTest.java

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Please create a ticket https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/new

Comment: thanks! i created a ticket https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/987

Answer (score 0):

For anybody coming to this at a later time:

This was a limitation of Spring Data JDBC. Thanks for finding it.

It is now properly implemented. The first version with the fix included is the 2.3 M1 release.

See [the issue created by Wansu yang](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/987) for details.